# Crystal reports isNumeric vs toNumber

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am handling a field that may or may not be a numerical value. If it is not-numerical, I'll just print it as is, if it is numerical, I will do some calculations on it, so I tried:

```
Local StringVar TxtUnct := {RESULT.ATTRIBUTE_1};
Local NumberVar Result := 0;
if not(isNumeric(TxtUnct)) Then(
    TxtUnct
);
Local NumberVar unct :=ToNumber(TxtUnct);
```

But I end up with a " The string is non-numeric." for the last line. Obiously, it looks numerical to isNumeric, but not to ToNumber. Are there any "stricter" checks in Crystal Reports?

Comment: A formula can only have one data type... it can't be a string in one case and a number in another.

Comment: This is just a part of it, I end up returning a string in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your representation is wrong... you are assigining first but as per your requirement assign if string is a number. So change like this.

```
Local StringVar TxtUnct;
Local NumberVar Result := 0;
if not(isNumeric(TxtUnct)) 
Then
(
    TxtUnct :={RESULT.ATTRIBUTE_1};
);
Local NumberVar unct :=ToNumber(TxtUnct)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just over-complicating it with all of those local variables. You can get it done with a simple `if-then-else` statement.

```
local numbervar workingNumber;

if not(isNumeric({RESULT.ATTRIBUTE_1}) then {RESULT.ATTRIBUTE_1}
 else
  (
   workingNumber:=toNumber({RESULT.ATTRIBUTE_1};
   //do your numeric calculations on workingNumber here
   toText(workingNumber)
  )
```